# Splitting String by Characters inside c#

Tags: c#

Im looking to split a string into certain sections. This is what i want to it to look like:

```
Original String : /abc/def/ghi
String1 : /abc
String2 : /abc/def
String3: /abc/def/ghi
```

Thanks in advance

```
string uri = "/abc/def/ghi";
string regex_text_dummy = Uri;
Regex first_part_regex = new Regex("^/.*/$");
path_stack[0] = Regex.Match(regex_test_dummy, first_part_regex);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your issue with that? Please read our [ask] topics.

Comment: Well you've kind of used some keywords for what you're trying to accomplish in your question. Have you tried [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: Yes, i have. I have currently tried Regex and string.split

Comment: Can you post your code snippets so we can help you try to correct your logic?

Comment: You really need to post your code. The answer to your question as stated is trivial.

Comment: I have posted my code above!

Comment: Strictly speaking, your code won't even compile.

Comment: `var parts = uri.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++) Console.WriteLine("/" + string.Join("/", parts.Take(i + 1)));`

Comment: Quick side note: `string regex_text_dummy = Uri;` needs a lower case `u`. Secondly, your regex is invalid. Your regex string wouldn't even capture your `uri` string because it doesn't end in a `/`, not to mention, you need to escape your slashes. `String.Split` would be significantly more appropriate for what you're attempting to accomplish. `string[] strings = uri.Split('/');`. Then you could loop through the string array and append the current index with the previous indices to get the values you've requested.

Comment: @RufusL That works, Thanks. If you want rep just post answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
      string Original_str = "/abc/def/ghi/ass/ddf/fgfg";
        string[] arr=Original_str.Split('/');
        string str="";

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            str += arr[x] +"/";
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```